# Why my google ads are showing in the countries I excluded?

Tags: ads, google-ad-manager

I have launched an Android app campaign, where I specifically target the Australian region by setting the targeting country to Australia.

However, after running the campaign for a month, I come to notice that Google is still showing my ads in other countries because I still have many downloads outside of Australia.
Please check the following user heat map:
[image]

As you can see there are 50% of users who downloaded my app through my google ads are outside of Australia.

Therefore, I start updating google ads settings to exclude those countries, however, I still keep getting the downloads from those countries.
The following is my google ad setup that shows the countries I excluded.
[image]

As you can see I excluded the country "Myanmar", however, after updating the settings for a week, I still get downloads from Myanmar.

As it is clearing wasting my budget for getting downloads outside of my targeting area, I am wondering what the resolution is.

I understand there could be people based in Australia but currently are outside of the country, however, the percentage is a bit too high in my case.

Thanks.